# Multiple form and php link

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a problem with my form. So in my `logandreg.html` I have 2 forms. One for login which is

```
<form method="post" action="valid.php">
  <p>
      Username: 
      <input type="text" name="login_username">
  </p>
  <p>
      Password: 
      <input type="password" name="login_pass">
  </p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="form-row login">
      <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login" name="login" class="button alt">
      </p>
```

and another form for register

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
  <p>
      Username: 
      <input type="text" name="username">
  </p>
  <p>
      Password: 
      <input type="password" name="pass">
  </p>
  <p>
      E-mail: 
      <input type="text" name="email">
  </p>                      
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="form-row reg">
      <p>
          <input type="submit" data-value="Register" value="Register" id="reg" name="reg" class="button alt">
      </p>
```

But why when I click on the submit button on the register part it always bring me to `valid.php` which is from the login form? Both of these form are in the same html. In the `valid.php` I have this

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {...}
    ?>
```

and in the `register.php` I have this

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['reg']))
        {...}
    ?>
```

Why does it always bring me to the `valid.php` when I click on the register button? Where is my mistake? Thanks

Comment: your code is too much clear just check in your html code if you really closing the </form> balise and also i see that there is a needed </div> before closing forms

Comment: oh ya. no wonder it doesnt work. was too blur didnt have the </form> tag thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit both of form using button, and trigger click event then relevent form submit event.

```
<form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="do_login.php">
    <input type="text" name="inp_1" id="inp_1"/>
    <button type="button" id="login_submit"></button>
</form>

<form name="registration" id="registration" method="post" action="do_registration.php">
    <input type="text" name="inp_2" id="inp_2"/>
    <button type="button" id="registration_submit"></button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#login_submit").click(function(){
        $("#login").submit();
    });


    $("#registration_submit").click(function(){
        $("#registration").submit();
    });
</script>
```